# VLC media player won't install

Tags: vlc

After typing `sudo apt install vlc` in the terminal, this is what I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 vlc : Depends: libgles1-mesa (>= 7.8.1) but it is not going to be installed or
                libgles1
       Depends: libgles2-mesa (>= 7.8.1) but it is not going to be installed or
                libgles2
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `lsb_release -a`, `apt-cache policy vlc libgles1\*`, and `dpkg-query -Wf '${Package}\t${Version}\t${Status}\t${Provides}\n' | awk -F '\t' 'index($4, "libgles1")'`? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo apt update
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt install -f
sudo apt install vlc
```

But if you want the latest version of vlc (Currently VLC 3.0), install from snap.

```
sudo snap install vlc
```

Answer (score 0):

Just go and install it from **Ubuntu Software Center**

After trying

```
sudo apt-get update –fix-missing
```

and

```
sudo dpkg –configure -a
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

the problem of a broken package still exist the solution is to edit the dpkg status file manually.

```
$ sudo nano /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

(you can use vim or gedit instead of nano)
Locate the corrupt package, and remove the whole block of information about it and save the file.

Information taken from [iasptk.com](http://www.iasptk.com/ubuntu-fix-broken-package-best-solution/)